# didnot search on searchbox in instagram

Tags: java, selenium

after login in instagram i want to search "tanishq" in searchbox.but it didn't search

```
 WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
         WebElement search = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[@class='eyXLr wUAXj ']")));
        search.click();
        search.clear();
        search.sendKeys("tanishq");
        List<WebElement> listofshop = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div//a//span[@class='Ap253']"));
        for(int k = 0;k<listofshop.size();k++) {
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        List<WebElement> photos = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='_9AhH0']"));
        for(int i=0;i<photos.size();i++) {
            photos.get(i).click();
            List<WebElement> tags = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a[@class='']"));
            for(int j=0;j<tags.size();j++) {
                System.out.println(tags.get(i).getText());
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use actions class and try

```
    Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
    actions.moveToElement(driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='_9AhH0']"));
    actions.click();
    actions.sendKeys("tanishq");
```